# How to calculate a groupby mean and variance in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, mean, pandas-groupby, variance

I have a DataFrame and I want to calculate the mean and the variance for each row for each person. Moreover, there is a column date and the chronological order must be respect when calculating the mean and the variance; the dataframe is already sorted by date. The date are just the number of day after the earliest date. The mean for the earliest date of a person row is simply the value in the column `Points` and the variance should be NAN or 0. Then, for the second date, the mean should be the means of the value in the column Points for this date and the previous one. Here is my code to generate the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=[["Al",0, 12],["Bob",2, 10],["Carl",5, 12],["Al",5, 5],["Bob",9, 2]
 ,["Al",22, 4],["Bob",22, 16],["Carl",33, 2],["Al",45, 7],["Bob",68, 4]
 ,["Al",72, 11],["Bob",79, 5]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Date", "Points"])
print(df)

     Name  Date  Points
0     Al     0      12
1    Bob     2      10
2   Carl     5      12
3     Al     5       5
4    Bob     9       2
5     Al    22       4
6    Bob    22      16
7   Carl    33       2
8     Al    45       7
9    Bob    68       4
10    Al    72      11
11   Bob    79       5
```

Here is my code to obtain the mean and the variance:

```
df['Mean'] = df.apply(
lambda x: df[(df.Name == x.Name) & (df.Date < x.Date)].Points.mean(), 
axis=1)

df['Variance'] = df.apply(
lambda x: df[(df.Name == x.Name)& (df.Date < x.Date)].Points.var(), 
axis=1)
```

However, the mean is shifted by one row and the variance by two rows. The dataframe obtained when sort by `Name`and `Date`is:

```
    Name    Date    Points  Mean    Variance
 0  Al       0       12      NaN        NaN
 3  Al       5       5     12.000000    NaN
 5  Al       22      4     8.50000  24.500000
 8  Al       45      7     7.000000 19.000000
10  Al       72      11    7.000000 12.666667
 1  Bob      2       10    NaN          NaN
 4  Bob      9       2     10.000000    NaN
 6  Bob      22      16    6.000000 32.000000
 9  Bob      68      4     9.333333 49.333333
11  Bob      79      5     8.000000 40.000000
2   Carl     5       12    NaN          NaN
7   Carl     33      2     12.000000    NaN
```

Instead, the dataframe should be as below:

```
Name        Date    Points  Mean    Variance
 0  Al       0       12      12       NaN
 3  Al       5       5       8.5      24.5
 5  Al       22      4       7        19
 8  Al       45      7       7        12.67
10  Al       72      11      7.8      ...
 1  Bob      2       10      10        NaN
 4  Bob      9       2       6        32
 6  Bob      22      16      9.33     49.33
 9  Bob      68      4       8        40
11  Bob      79      5       7.4      ...
2   Carl     5       12      12       NaN
7   Carl     33      2       7        50
```

What should I change ?

Comment: I would suggest using `df.Date <= x.Date` for a quick fix, but I think there might be simpler ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, it is working by modifying `<` for `<=`